# Connecting two canvas objects in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am developing an application using Fabric.js and HTML5 canvas. I have 2 rectangles in canvas. I want to connect these 2 rectangles using line which will be created by user by dragging the mouse. And also, when user drags a rectangle, the lines should remain fixed with that rectangle.

Please guide me in solving this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This should get you started — http://fabricjs.com/stickman